# On click remove/add of classes.

Tags: javascript, class, onclick

Okay, So what I want is if you click class .bookclick, another class called .book will change. Everything worked when I did:

```
  $(".book").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('Offline') )   $(this).removeClass('Offline').addClass('Activebook');
    else    $(this).addClass('Offline')
  })
```

but, this messes with some links within the content.(if I click anywhere within .book, it changes and interferes with the functionality of the links.)

I tried to do this, but it does not quit work.

```
  $(".bookclick").click(function(){
    if ( $('.book').hasClass('Offline') )   $(this).removeClass('Offline').addClass('Activebook');
    else    $('.book').addClass('Offline')


 })
```

Here is the fiddle of the entire website:

https://jsfiddle.net/e3aqnwb8/

Hopefully someone will see the mistake I made! Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: u must have styles or scripts that are looking for `.Offline`? When you remove it; those will stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you forgot to replace one of the `this`s with .book

```
  $(".bookclick").click(function(){
if ( $('.book').hasClass('Offline') )   $('.book').removeClass('Offline').addClass('Activebook');
else    $('.book').addClass('Offline')
```

})

Comment: Oh god hahahaha. That's it. I can't believe it did not see that. I feel embarrassed now.

Comment: @LLeah sure thing! Don't sweat it, we all do it from time to time :-)